# Proving convergence to normal distribution using the delta method

Tags: self-study, central-limit-theorem, delta-method, slutsky-theorem

The following is a question and instructor provided solution from a recent exam I took.

Question:
Prove that $\sqrt{n}T_n$ converges in distribution to N(0, 4).

$T_n$=$(\bar{X}^2 - \hat{\sigma}^2)/\hat{\sigma}^2$

With the X's being a random sample from an exponential population with unit mean.

Solution provided:
The desired result follows from Slutsky's theorem if we can show that $\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}^2 - \hat{\sigma}^2)$ is asymptotically N(0, 4). The latter will be verified by the delta method (computation for this below).

I understand the computation for the delta method. My question is why and how showing that $\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}^2 - \hat{\sigma}^2)$ is asymptotically N(0, 4) also shows that $\sqrt{n}T_n$ converges in distribution to N(0, 4)? Essentially, what is happening to the $\hat{\sigma}^2$ in the denominator of $T_n$?

Updated attempt:

If $\sqrt{n}T_n$=$\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}^2 - \hat{\sigma}^2)/\hat{\sigma}^2$ converges in distribution to N(0, 4), then $\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}^2 - \hat{\sigma}^2)$ converges in distribution to N(0, 4*$\hat{\sigma}^4$).

$\hat{\sigma}^2$ converges to ${\sigma}^2$ by the WLLN.

Because the distribution of X's is exponential($\beta$=1), ${\sigma}^2$ = ${\beta}^2$ = 1^2 = 1.

So, $\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}^2 - \hat{\sigma}^2)$ converges in distribution to N(0, 4*$\hat{\sigma}^4$) = N(0, 4*${\sigma}^4$) = N(0, 4*1^2) = N(0, 4).

Can anyone confirm whether this is a correct interpretation/solution?

*** The N(0, 8) in the question stem of part (b) was confirmed to be a typo. It should be N(0, 4).

[image: problem]

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer, it is best not to add the `[self-study]` tag for the OP, but to ask them to do it & read its wiki. Then there is a better chance they will be familiar w/ our policies. If they don't add the tag, that is a signal to us to close the question.

Comment: Please type your question as text, do not just post a photograph (see 
[here](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/a/3176/)). When you retype the question,
add the `[self-study]` tag & read 
[its wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). 
Then tell us what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. 
We'll provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: The point is moot since the OP gave it the self study tag.  It is clear though that it is not homework the OP said it was an exam problem and after the exam the instructor gave it as a solution. The OP is just trying to understand the the instructors solution or if it is wrong to get a correct answer.  It is an interesting question that deserves to stay open.  I can see suggesting that it might be self study but threatening closer if not tagged that way is the wrong approach. Now we have an obligation to only give hints when the OP really needs a complete answer if he can't solve it himself.

Comment: Is there something else I need to do here? I'm sorry if the post was not completely correct, but I'm doing my best and would really just appreciate some help...

Comment: Should I remove the self-study tag?

Comment: No, you need to leave it. You don't need to do anything more. SS isn't just homework, this qualifies.